# Power Query takes forever, doesn't work with large amounts of API queries

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm using this Power Query:

```
let 
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="api_requests"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Syntax", type text}, {"protocol", type text}, {"wsEntryPoint", type text}, {"resource", type text}, {"flowRef", type text}, {"key", type text}, {"parameters", type text}, {"Full API request", type text}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Full API request"}),
    #"Kept Range of Rows" = Table.Range(#"Removed Other Columns",0,100),
    url_list = #"Kept Range of Rows"[Full API request],
    combined_results = Table.Combine(List.Transform(url_list, each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document(Web.Contents(_, [Timeout=#duration(0,0,60,0)]),[Delimiter=",", Columns=32, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]), [PromoteAllScalars=true])))
 
in combined_results
```

to download data from the european central bank via their API; the API URLS needed are stored in a worksheet called API Requests. There are about 1000 API calls in total.

This works fine for 50 or so API calls, but even with 100 (as shown in the code below) the code just runs forever without doing anything. The code is supposed to download those 1000 csvs then combine them into a new worksheet, which works fine for a few csvs and doesn't work with much more than fifty. Without the [Timeout=#duration(0,0,60,0)] i just get a timeout error.

I tested downloading all the csvs via Python (via pd.read_csv()) and it works fine there, takes just 2-3 minutes to get all 1000.

Is there anything I can do here? Consolidating the API requests by e.g. using wildcards etc. could work, but I don't really know much about the data, I'm just trying to do the technical data import side so others can work with it.

edit: I tried this suggestion

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="api_requests"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Syntax", type text}, {"protocol", type text}, {"wsEntryPoint", type text}, {"resource", type text}, {"flowRef", type text}, {"key", type text}, {"parameters", type text}, {"Full API request", type text}}),
#"Kept Range of Rows" = Table.FirstN( #"Changed Type" ,1050),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(  #"Kept Range of Rows", "Custom", each Csv.Document(Web.Contents([Full API request], [Timeout=#duration(0,0,60,0)]),[Delimiter=",", Columns=32, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])),
tables_with_headers = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "step2", each Table.PromoteHeaders([Custom], [PromoteAllScalars=true]))
in  tables_with_headers
```

Weirdly, it seems to buckle under the PromoteHeaders line and does not finish loading.

Comment: What happens if you add custom column on  #"Kept Range of Rows" that just pulls Csv.Document() ?  Also whats the #"Filtered Rows"  step supposed to be doing?

Comment: I removed the Filtered Rows step, it wasn't doing anything. Can you explain your first comment? I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what does this do with and the without the timeout part?

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="api_requests"]}[Content],
#"Kept Range of Rows" = Table.FirstN( Source ,100),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(  #"Kept Range of Rows", "Custom", each Csv.Document(Web.Contents([Full API request], [Timeout=#duration(0,0,60,0)]),[Delimiter=",", QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])),
tables_with_headers = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "step2", each Table.PromoteHeaders([Custom], [PromoteAllScalars=true]))
in tables_with_headers
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work fine, but when I add the PromoteHeaders part, it goes back to infinite loading mode. I don't see why that part would be problematic; the tables have diffeent columns, so I need to get proper headings in order to combine the tables.

Comment: It's the Table.PromoteHeaders command around the Csv.Document... part.

Comment: I added the proposed lines to my original post; for some reason the PromoteHeaders line does not finish loading. And again, everything works if I limit everything to 50 csvs, or if I remove the PromoteHeaders line. Very strange.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas. That should work fine. Perhaps someone else will be able to help