# How can I join a list of tables on a common column?

Tags: excel, powerquery

Loosely related to this question

[Power Query takes forever, doesn't work with large amounts of API queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810150/power-query-takes-forever-doesnt-work-with-large-amounts-of-api-queries/76811162#76811162)

Say I have a table in Power Query where one column has a table in each row; how can I join all those tables in that column together (on a common column, say with an outer join).

In the question linked, Table.combine was used to combine all tables in the specified column. But as far as I can tell, Table.join only accepts two tables, not a list of tables.

I know this is possible in Python with Pandas, so I assumed I could do something similar in PowerQuery. Is there any way to join a list of tables as described above?

edit: current code

```
let 
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="api_requests"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Syntax", type text}, {"protocol", type text}, {"wsEntryPoint", type text}, {"resource", type text}, {"flowRef", type text}, {"key", type text}, {"parameters", type text}, {"Full API request", type text}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Target Sheet] = "Kreditzinsen")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Custom", each Csv.Document(Web.Contents([Full API request], [Timeout=#duration(0,0,60,0)]),[Delimiter=";", Columns=3, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])),
tables_with_headers = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "step2", each Table.PromoteHeaders([Custom], [PromoteAllScalars=true])),
tables_without_empty_key = Table.AddColumn(tables_with_headers, "step3", each Table.SelectRows([step2], each ([#""] <> ""))),
tables = Table.SelectColumns(tables_without_empty_key,{"step3"}),
Custom = tables[step3],
combined_results = List.Accumulate(Custom, 0, (state, current) => if state = 0 then current else Table.RemoveColumns(Table.Join(Table.RenameColumns(state, {"", "Col1"}), "Col1", current, "", JoinKind.FullOuter), "Col1")),
RemovedColumnList = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(combined_results), each Text.EndsWith(_, "_FLAGS")),
RemovedColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(combined_results, RemovedColumnList)
in
RemovedColumns
```

Comment: You can use `List.Accumulate` for this. Still limited to two at a time, but you can progress through the column joining each table to the previous joining.

Comment: This works very well @RonRosenfeld. The only thhing that doesn't work is Outer Joins as all my tables have the same Key column name (Inner join works, though). This might be a seperate problem though.

Comment: In that case, you may have to do nested joins, or change the name of the key column for the "current" table so you don't create duplicates, and then eliminate them all at the end.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld : Thanks for the input! I tried renaming, then removing the key column (within the List.Accumulate) but then I end up without any key column at the end. Outer joins seem very cumbersome with PowerQuery compared to Python Pandas or SQL. Haven't tried the NestedJoin approach (as I currently don't fully understand how nested joins work).

Comment: Either approach should work, but since you've posted neither data nor code, I can't help you further.

Comment: @RonRosenfeldI can easily fix that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without data it is difficult to reproduce, but the code below might give you an idea.

- The code and comments should help you with the algorithm.
- Note that deleting the various Key columns is optional.

```
let

//create sample tables
    Table1 = #table({"A","B","C","KEY"},{{1,2,3,"X"},{4,5,6,"Y"},{7,8,9,"Z"}}),
    Table2 = #table({"D","E","F","KEY"},{{10,11,12,"Z"},{13,14,15,"Y"},{16,17,18,"X"}}),
    Table3 = #table({"G","H","I","KEY"},{{19,20,21,"W"},{22,23,24,"Z"},{25,26,27,"Y"}}),

//Make a column of just tables
    Tables = Table.FromList({Table1,Table2,Table3},Splitter.SplitByNothing(),type table[Tables=table]),

//Join them, always renaming the KEY columns according to the row number
//  Hopefully, you won't have any native columns named with a number (as text)
    #"Joined Tables" = 
        List.Generate(
            ()=>[t=Tables[Tables]{0}, idx=0],
            each [idx] < Table.RowCount(Tables),
            each [t=Table.Join(Table.RenameColumns([t], {"KEY", Text.From([idx])}),Text.From([idx]), Tables[Tables]{[idx]+1},"KEY", JoinKind.FullOuter), idx=[idx]+1],
            each [t]),

//This is optional if you want to remove the Key columns    
    #"Remove Keys" = 
        let 
            tbl = List.Last(#"Joined Tables"),
            #"Remove Key Cols" = 
                Table.RemoveColumns(
                    tbl,
                    List.Select(
                        Table.ColumnNames(tbl), 
                            each List.Contains(
                                List.Transform({0..Table.RowCount(Tables)}, each Text.From(_)),_))
                                & {"KEY"})
        in 
            #"Remove Key Cols"


in
    #"Remove Keys"
```

The above results in this final table:
[image]